# I manually add `Content-Encoding: br` and it does not work

Tags: http, http-headers, reverse-proxy, brotli

Using homemade [proxy](https://github.com/vporton/wikipedia-upload/tree/7fb088a7b3e7cc7818427f6dc32ccacf97aeccd6/proxy) software that adds/removes headers as specified (yes, I violate proxy standards), I add `Content-Encoding: br` to a file in Brotli format served by the upstream:

```bash
docker run --net=host --rm proxy /root/proxy/target/release/proxy --port 8080 http://localhost:1633 \
    -A "Content-Encoding: br" -R "Accept-Ranges" -R "Content-Length" -R "Decompressed-Content-Length"
```

(`-A` flags add headers, `-R` flags remove headers).

Then I add yet one proxy level, Apache (with the purpose to add SSL):

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/bzz/"
```

A request https://test.vporton.name/008e1e5b3e2f4f2cf04a48e49c2fdafeac6e9a01f0159c6881812e919f4f8476/index.html to Apache returns:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 05 Jun 2022 03:43:53 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
< content-encoding: br
< x-forwarded-server: test.vporton.name
< user-agent: curl/7.81.0
< x-forwarded-host: test.vporton.name
< accept: */*
< host: localhost:8080
< x-forwarded-for: 87.71.212.18
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
```

When I try to open it in a browser, it (for Firefox) tells about bad page encoding or (for Chrome) shows empty page. Why did I do wrong? (Clearing cache and restarting the browser does not work.)

I am sure that file is correctly encoded as Brotli:

```
curl https://test.vporton.name/008e1e5b3e2f4f2cf04a48e49c2fdafeac6e9a01f0159c6881812e919f4f8476/index.html | brotli --test
```

returns no error. Moreover,

```
curl https://test.vporton.name/008e1e5b3e2f4f2cf04a48e49c2fdafeac6e9a01f0159c6881812e919f4f8476/index.html | brotli --decompress
```

produces a HTML file as intended.

Comment: Maybe it is caused by me changing the window size to 24 when compressing with Brotli? May browsers not support this?

Comment: Apparently, the error is related to `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`?!